# How to simplify case and like with regexp in oracle table join

Tags: sql, regex, database, oracle, join

I have this query and it works as I expect it  to. Now I want to try to simplify it, especially in the marked part. As you can see here, the like condition triggers only when gr.season_out is not a blank space, else join only on the first condition. This is exactly how I want it to be. I want to try regexp and maybe get rid of the case altogether if possible. I don;t know, do I need to use regexp_substr, regexp_like or both?

```
select sart.season, ost.art, ost.asize, sum(ost.kol) as sum_kol, gr.shopid from 
ost inner join sart on ost.art = sart.art
---Important---
inner join gr on
(
ost.id_shop = gr.shopid and
case
when gr.season_out != ' ' and ', ' || gr.season_out || ',' like '%, ' || sart.season || ',%' then 1
when gr.season_out = ' ' then 1
else 0
end = 1
)
----------------
where gr.s_group = '12345'
group by sart.season, gr.shopid, ost.art, ost.asize having sum(ost.kol) > 0
order by ost.art, ost.asize;
```

I can't change the model it is not mine I can only simplify queries

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what the code should be doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This logic should be equivalent to:

```
inner join gr
on ost.id_shop = gr.shopid and
   (gr.season_out = ' ' or
    ', ' || gr.season_out || ',' like '%, ' || sart.season || ',%'
   )
```

You don't need a `case` expression in the `on` clause.  I should note that storing multiple values in a single column is a very bad idea.  The data model should be fixed.